# time on files differ by 1 sec. FAIL Robocopy sync

Tags: backup

I am trying to use Robocopy to sync (/IMG) a folder on my PC and a shared network drive.

The problem is that the file attributes differ by 1 sec on both locations (creation,modified and access). So every time I run robocopy, it syncs the file again...

BTW, problem is the same if I delete the target file and robocopy it from new... still, new file has 1 sec different properties.

Env Details:

- Source: Win 7 64 bit
- Target: WD My Book World Edition NAS 1TB which takes its time from online NTP pool.ntp.org (I don't know if file system is FAT or not)

Comment: Wouldn't this question be more appropriate on serverfault or superuser ?

Comment: It may be because the two machine have a diverging clock. Try to synchronize the time with the same NTP server on both machines. There is also an option to robocopy to allow small divergence on the timestamp. I think this is `robocopy /MIR /FFT` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the target filesystem is formatted for DOS, i.e. the FAT filesystem, it can only store modification timestamps with a resolution of two seconds, as documented here: [File Times](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx)

Sylvain's suggestion to use robocopy's /fft option should address the problem.

Comment: /fft solves the problem. but it is a external drive, so I am not sure about FAT or not being the issue.

Comment: External drives are actually FAT formatted for compatibility quite often, so it's pretty likely.